# Images in tableview load another for a few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have an image in tableview that is downloaded from a Json, everything works perfect but when scrolling before seeing the corresponding image it loads another for a few seconds (these images are those that are already visible in the table).

The structure of my data is:

```
struct Data: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let img: String
    let phone: String
    let linktaller: String
    let web: String
}
```

The code of my cell where the image is loaded is:

```
             func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? AseguradorasTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }



        cell.titleLbl.text = company[indexPath.row].name
        .
        .
        .

         // load image
        if let imageURL = URL(string: company[indexPath.row].img) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                if let data = data {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.myImage.image = image


                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return cell

 }
```

The function to load the data is:

```
    func downloadJSON() {

        let url = URL(string: "http://myserver.com/data.json")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                do {
                    self.company = try JSONDecoder().decode([Data].self, from: data!)

                    print(self.company)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    }

                } catch let jsonError{
                    print("error + \(jsonError)")
                }
            }
            }.resume()

   }
```

See image for more detail:

[image: image screen]

Any suggestions are welcome to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following class for cache image support:

```
class ImageLoader {

    var cache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

    class var sharedInstance : ImageLoader {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ image: UIImage?, _ url: String) -> ()) {
        let data: NSData? = self.cache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? NSData

        if let imageData = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(image, urlString)
            }
            return
        }

        let downloadTask: URLSessionDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL.init(string: urlString)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if data != nil {
                    let image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
                    self.cache.setObject(data! as AnyObject, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completionHandler(image, urlString)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, urlString)
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}
```

In the cell, load the image as follows:

```
        // Load image
        let fimage = company[indexPath.row].img

        ImageLoader.sharedInstance.imageForUrl(urlString: fimage, completionHandler: { (image, url) in
            if image != nil {

                cell.myImage.image = image

            }
        })
```

With that, the download of the images should work correctly

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In UITableView `dequeueReusableCell`- Each UITableViewCell will be reused several times with different data(image).
In your case, every `cellForRowAt` is called, the image will be load from server so it will have delay.
Solution: You must to cache image with url in local app when the image load finish.
(1)- Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) - with cache support
(2)- You can save image in a array ->  in  `cellForRowAt` load from this array if existed and load from server if does not exist

(image from internet)

Answer (score 0):

Because of when ever the cell is showing, you download the image from internet by

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
```

You should

1. Check if image in `imageURL` has cached or not
2. If cached, load image from local
3. If not cache, download it from internet, then cache it.

Or just simple using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or anything else, it will auto check the step 1 to 3 for you :D

For example by using SDWebImage

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "your_image_url"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic cell reuse problem. You should install a placeholder image, or nil, into the image view of each cell in your `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` method before you begin the download. That will clear out the previous image that was installed into the cell, and then the async download can run in the background and install the image once it's done loading.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve similar issues, I changed my code to coordinate the downloading of images with the creation of tableView cells, storing the images in a local array.


I create a dictionary array to hold the downloaded images, using the url string as the key:


imagesArray = [String:UIImage]()


Then, at the point in the code where each image completes downloading, I add the image to the array and insert one new row into the tableView:


imagesArray.updateValue(UIImage(data: data!)!, forKey: imageURL as! String)


tableView.beginUpdates()


tableView.insertRows(at:[IndexPath(row: imagesArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)


tableView.endUpdates()


tableView.reloadData()


I also maintain a separate array of information elements for each image, including the image url string as one element. This allows me to present the correct items in the tableView cell:


cell.itemNameLabel.text = itemRecords[indexPath.row].itemName
cell.itemImage.image = imagesArray[itemRecords[indexPath.row].imageURL]


While the images are downloading, I present a progress indicator spinner.


Once the images are all downloaded and are loaded into the imagesArray, there is NO delay in presenting as the user scrolls up and down to view the listed cells, and reused cells are loaded with the correct images.